# Implementing reCaptcha in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, recaptcha

I am trying to insert a captcha in my ASP.NET code. Basically, in the `lbt_proceed_click()` method, I want the browser to proceed to the next page using `Response.Redirect("foo")` only if the captcha entered is correct.

I searched, but could not find a solution, especially since I am not using a form to send data, but writing to a database directly, and then moving to the next page using `Response.Redirect()`.

Comment: can you show the code how you implemented Recaptcha without using Forms

Comment: Have you ever visited [Using reCAPTCHA with ASP.NET](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html)?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna- I am not able to.. no idea how.

Comment: @abatishchev- I did, but the example there uses a form. Help?

Comment: @user1016313: Don't use `-` in `@`. Otherwise users don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to the [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) site and register for a unique key
2. Download [reCAPTCHA .NET Library](https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest)
3. [Create](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create) and Save your Public and Private keys safely
   [image: Create Public and Private Key]
   [image: Save Public and Private Key]
4. In the website we add a reference to library/bin/Release/Recaptcha.dll
5. after the @Page directive, insert the following code:

   ```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha"%>
   ```
6. add control in asp.net  tag:

   ```
           <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl

           ID="recaptcha"

           runat="server"

           PublicKey="Your very own public key here"

           PrivateKey="Your very own privat key here"

      />
   ```
7. add button and label to your form
8. add the following button click method(btnSubmit_Click) in code behind file  :

   ```
   if (Page.IsValid)
   {   
       lblResult.Text = "You Got It!"; // Or Use Response.redirect("foo");
   }
        else
   {
       lblResult.Text = "Incorrect";
   }
   ```
9. Test your Page!

Comment: You should rather link to the current download page: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest