# How do i use recaptcha asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to implement validate Google RECaptcha version 2.0 on Client Side using JavaScript and jQuery in ASP.Net?
The Google RECaptcha version 2.0 allows to validate the Captcha response on client side using its Callback functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var onloadCallback = function () {
    grecaptcha.render('dvCaptcha', {
        'sitekey': '<%=ReCaptcha_Key %>',
        'callback': function (response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/VerifyCaptcha",
                data: "{response: '" + response + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var captchaResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(r.d);
                    if (captchaResponse.success) {
                        $("[id*=txtCaptcha]").val(captchaResponse.success);
                        $("[id*=rfvCaptcha]").hide();
                    } else {
                        $("[id*=txtCaptcha]").val("");
                        $("[id*=rfvCaptcha]").show();
                        var error = captchaResponse["error-codes"][0];
                        $("[id*=rfvCaptcha]").html("RECaptcha error. " + error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement reCaptcha for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: There is huge different between ASP.Net and MVC.

Comment: check other questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764692/validating-recaptcha-2-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-asp-nets-server-side) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515838/new-google-recaptcha-with-asp-net), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102549/how-to-implement-recaptcha-2-0-on-asp-net), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443616/implementing-recaptcha-in-asp-net)